# How to position line data points to middle of bar in bar/line graph using ChartJS

Tags: javascript, html, charts, chart.js

I'm making a combination bar/line chart using Chart.js v2. I want the line data to match up exactly with the bar data when being displayed given that there are two sets of bar chart data. Here is what I have now:[image]

But I really want each blue data point on the line graph to match up to the top-middle of each blue bar, and each green data point to match up to the top-middle of each green bar, instead of them being placed in the center of the "x value". I can't seem to figure out how to do this given the Chart.js documentation.

Here is my code:

```
var monthlyDownloadsData = {
    labels: ["3 Months","2 Months","Last Month","This Month","Next Month"],
    datasets: [{
        label: "App Store",
        data: [150, 175, 135, 120, 115],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 179, 255, 1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
    }, {
        label: "Google Play",
        data: [130, 105, 115, 95, 75],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(140, 255, 102, 1)",
        borderColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 1)"
    }, {
        type: "line",
        label: "App Store",
        data: [150, 175, 135, 120, 115],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(102, 179, 255, 0.5)"
    }, {
        type: "line",
        label: "Google Play",
        data: [130, 105, 115, 95, 75],
        backgroundColor: "rgba(140, 255, 102, 0.5)"
    }]
};

var monthlyDownloadsOptions = {
    title: {
        display: false
    },
    scales: {
        xAxes: [{
            gridlines: {
                display: false
            }
        }]
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false
};

var monthlyDownloads = document.getElementById('monthlydownloads').getContext('2d');
new Chart(monthlyDownloads, {
    type: 'bar',
    data: monthlyDownloadsData,
    options: monthlyDownloadsOptions
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to do this. The main reason being that there's no way to relate one dataset to another. The chart has no way of knowing that the blue line is associated to the blue bar and therefore should center it with the blue bar, and the same for the green ones. You could probably create a plug-in to do this, but I didn't know if you would be interested in that solution.

Comment: If you used a stacked bar instead, then it would all line up correctly.  Here is an [example](http://codepen.io/jordanwillis/pen/jBxrzM)